# How can I disable the "Error summary" under the form in Orbeon

Tags: orbeon

How can I disable the "Error summary" under the form in Orbeon? I just want the error to appear under the field and not under the form.

In the documentation: By specifying the `incremental="false"` attribute, errors only show on demand with the fr-update and fr-clear events.

Where does the following code go? Does it work?

```
<xf:dispatch name="fr-clear" targetid="my-error-summary"/>
```

Is there a specific property to do this or is there any specific configurations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the error summary by setting the [following property](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/form-runner-detail-page.html#position-of-error-summary):

```
<property
    as="xs:string"
    name="oxf.fr.detail.error-summary.*.*"
    value="none"/>
```

And if you haven't worked with the `properties-local.xml` yet, you might want to read more about [properties](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/).